# How to count tokens?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to extract words out of a string and count them (to say how often a word occurs).

```
val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(title)
val words = tokenized.select("words").take(5).foreach(println)
```

What i get is a Format like this.

```
[WrappedArray(rt, happy, new, year!!! ]
[WrappedArray(rt, happy, new, year!!! ]
[WrappedArray(rt, happy, new, year!!! ]
[WrappedArray(rt, happy, new, year!!! ]
[WrappedArray(rt, happy, new, year!!! ]
```

What i want to is get a count by word list grouped by the words. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of *explode* and *groupBy* with *count* aggregation, like this:

```
tokenized.withColumn("words", explode(col("words")))
  .groupBy("words")
  .agg(count("*")).show()
```